# Where to find absolutely free responsive templates for Joomla on the web?

Tags: templates, responsive-web-design

I have been searching the web for a an absolutely free template that has a red color shopping portal theme/layout. The issue is when i try to download the template, I am prompted to join the portal as a member via paying a certain amount of fee.
Can someone guide me here for an absolutely free and responsive Joomla template portal from where I can download my desired template? Thank you

Comment: google would give you better answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hundreds of free Joomla templates on the web, it really depends on what you consider to be 'good quality' There are few good quality free templates out there.

Firstly,

- what version of Joomla?
- what framework are you looking to use?
- what shopping cart are you going to implement?

Remember that if you do see a theme you like it's very easy to customise the colour to your red requirements using css.

I can only speak from experience but I can recommend Joomlart (http://www.joomlart.com/) GavickPro (http://www.gavick.com/) and JoomlaXTC (http://www.joomlaxtc.com/). They all have a free version of some sort, worth a look.

Some of the best templates are worth paying for and offer excellent support, plus it's always nice to give back to the developer(s) that have worked so hard on creating the template in the first place.

Comment: Hi! Version of Joomla is 3.3. We need to build a Shopping Mall web portal that has to be responsive.

Comment: I have tried to help you as per my post above, I suggest you do some more research.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases what you are really paying for is support. Providing support costs template companies a lot of time and money.

When you pay nothing for a template you can expect to get zero support, and if you are not an experienced Joomla developer then it is probably support that you need more than anything.

Getting free templates is easy. Turning them into what you need is the hard bit. If you see a template that provides everything you need you should pay for it. The chances that a free template will magically provide everything you need is the same as the level of support you get; zero.